# PHP Updating Array Values Issue

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very beginner level question here - I've tried googling around and reading the PHP.net tutorials and as obvious it seems to update an array I'm not having any luck.

This is my issue.

In my code is the line:

```
$router = Router::get(array('appDirectory' => dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
```

On looking into this, I want to update this section:

```
(array('appDirectory' => dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
```

which with a var_dump gives the following:

```
array(1) { ["appDirectory"]=> string(40) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hockey/hockey/" }
```

I want that to be:

```
array(1) { ["appDirectory"]=> string(40) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hockey/hockey/SOMEOTHERADD" }
```

Any help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Well then just concatenate `'SOMEOTHERADD'` to the end of the value you are passing to the method …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array1 = array('appDirectory' => dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

//if you wish to update before assigning:
$array1['appDirector'] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hockey/hockey/SOMEOTHERADD";

$router = Router::get($array1);

//if after var $router is an array from your var_dump example

$router['appDirector'] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hockey/hockey/SOMEOTHERADD";

var_dump($router); //This should produce array(1) { ["appDirectory"]=> string(40) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hockey/hockey/SOMEOTHERADD" }
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the array in your example, simply do

```
 
  $array["appDirectory"] = $array["appDirectory"] . 'attache-string';
```

That should resolve the problem.

Hope the answer is clear and it helps.